# Install VS 2019 on Windows Server 2019 throws virtual memory low error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-server-2019

I try to install my VS 2019 on my Windows Server 2019 VM Ware.
This VM Ware is given as a fact, so I can't switch this server or OS.

The main install is okay, but when try to install the APS.Net Package, it throws this error:
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Registry,version=16.11.31503.43' failed to install.
Search URL
https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Registry;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=635
Details
Command executed: "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Registry,version=16.11.31503.43\ScriptedSandboxSecurityZone.exe" -Action=Install
Return code: 635
Return code details: {Virtual Memory Minimum Too Low}
Your system is low on virtual memory. Windows is increasing the size of your virtual memory paging file.
During this process, memory requests for some applications may be denied. For more information, see Help.
Log
C:\Users\kor0006\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20210812162459_001_Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Registry.log

I have tried to set the virtual memory to 4GB, 12GB and 20GB but no change.

Comment: [This is a known issue with Visual Studio 2019](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PackageId:MicrosoftVisualStudioScripte/1490305).  You can try installing 16.10.4 until the issue is resolved.  You can also try disabling `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration`.  You can view the current state of the setting by going to `res://iesetup.dll/SoftAdmin.htm` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to install my VS 2019 on my Windows Server 2019 VM Ware. This VM Ware is given as a fact, so I can't switch this server or OS.

You have ran into a bug within Visual Studio itself.  You will want to downgrade to the previous version [16.10.31515.178](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) for the time being.

However, there appears to be a workaround that might exist:

> [Workaround]
> On Windows Server 2019 try disabling “Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration”

Once you disable `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration` you will want to perform a repair install of Visual Studio and attempt to reinstall the component in question.

You might have to modify your Internet Security Zone Entries within your group policy.

> You can test it on w2019s with Internet Explorer - Internet Options. If you can set manually the Zone-Entries the update should work. **If the Edit-Mode of the Zone-Entries is disabled by GPO the Update will also fail.**  If you cannot perform the workaround then you will have to downgrade to 16.10.31515.178 until it's fixed.

Source: [PackageId:Microsoft.VisualStudio.ScriptedHost.Registry;PackageAction:Install;ReturnCode:635;](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/PackageId:MicrosoftVisualStudioScripte/1490305)